# How can I convert .pdf to .docx file with libreoffice-convert using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pdf, docx, libreoffice

I want to convert .pdf to .docx file with libreoffice-convert using nodejs and [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert). This is an example code from this package. How can I use this example?

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const libre = require('libreoffice-convert');
libre.convertAsync = require('util').promisify(libre.convert);

async function main() {
    const ext = '.docx'
    const inputPath = path.join(__dirname, '/resources/example.pdf');
    const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, `/resources/example${ext}`);
    const file = await fs.readFile(inputPath);
    let conv = await libre.convertAsync(file, ext, undefined);
    await fs.writeFile(outputPath, conv);
}

main().catch(function (err) {
    console.log(`Error converting file: ${err}`);
});
```

Comment: The code you pasted is hard to read, not formatted and also apparently invalid, looks like back-ticks `` instead of 'single-quotes', and an _"'enter code here`"_ string sequence somewhere in the middle

Comment: can you post any suggestion how can i convert file?pdf to docx

Comment: https://tutorialforbeginner.com/artificial-intelligence-tutorial

Comment: https://tutorialforbeginner.com/machine-learning-tutorial

Comment: https://tutorialforbeginner.com/deep-learning-tutorial